# Given Circle $E$ inscribed in square $ABCD,$ prove that its radius is equal to half the length of the square's side length.

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

Given Circle $E$ inscribed in square $ABCD$, prove that its radius is equal to half the length of the square's side length. I'm stuck on this proof but I've got a few ideas. If anyone could help that would be awesome.

1. Draw radii $EF$ and $EG$ so that $EF$ is perpendicular to $CD$ and $EG$ is perpendicular to $AD$
2. With this, we now have a quadrilateral $EFDG$.
3. The presence of congruent and opposite angles implies that the new quadrilateral formed is a rectangle.
4. $EF$  is congruent to $GD$ and $EG$ is congruent to $FD$.

Comment: $EF$ and $EG$ are radii, then $EF$ is also congruent to $EG$. Add radii $EH$ perpendicular to $BC$, then $EH=CF$, $EH+EG=CF+FD=CD$.

Comment: Your construction doesn't make an obvious use of the key assumption, that the square $ABCD$ has *inscribed* circle $E$.  Possibly this is related to reusing letter $E$ as an endpoint(?) in each radius $EF$ and $EG$ you set out to draw, which implies $E$ is the *center* of circle $E$.  Avoid abuse of notation when there is enough confusion already.  I would instead approach the setup by labelling points where the circle is tangent to the edges of the square.

Comment: What happen with MSE? Putting this problem in section **Can you answer this questions** of Newsletter seems inappropriate.